# How can I retrieve the current test's name within a Mocha test?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

For additional logging, I need to be able to print the current test's description.

How can I do this (with Mocha BDD)?

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
console.log(this.title);
```

Comment: doesn't work. should be this.test.title as in @louis answer below

Answer (score 57):

If you are directly inside a callback to `describe`, you can use `this.title` for the title of the `describe` or `this.fullTitle()` to get the hierarchical title of the `describe` (ancestors' titles + the title of this one). If you are inside a callback to `it` you can use `this.test.title` or `this.test.fullTitle()` respectively. So:

```
describe("top", function() {
    console.log(this.title);
    console.log(this.fullTitle());

    it("test", function () {
        console.log(this.test.title);
        console.log(this.test.fullTitle());
    });
});
```

The `console.log` statements above will output:

```
top
top
test
top test
```

Here's a fuller example that shows how the titles change depending on nesting:

```
function dump () {
    console.log("running: (fullTitle)", this.test.fullTitle(), "(title)",
                this.test.title);
}

function directDump() {
    console.log("running (direct): (fullTitle)", this.fullTitle(), "(title)",
                this.title);
}

describe("top", function () {
    directDump.call(this);
    it("test 1", dump);
    it("test 2", dump);
    describe("level 1", function () {
        directDump.call(this);
        it("test 1", dump);
        it("test 2", dump);
    });
});
```

The `console.log` statements will output:

```
running (direct): (fullTitle) top (title) top
running (direct): (fullTitle) top level 1 (title) level 1
running: (fullTitle) top test 1 (title) test 1
running: (fullTitle) top test 2 (title) test 2
running: (fullTitle) top level 1 test 1 (title) test 1
running: (fullTitle) top level 1 test 2 (title) test 2
```

Comment: Could you point to Mocha's documentation where API like `this.test.fullTitle( )` is documented? It would be great for the public to know ,explore and find answers to questions like this and more.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation in this area is lacking. If you are concerned about the stability of this API, what I can say is that reporters use this to produce their reports so if the Mocha devs just changed it, they'd break third party reporters.

Comment: A little late, but this might help: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/test.js

Comment: Note, this only works when using `it('name', function () {` syntax. `this` is undefined when using arrow functions `() => {`

Answer (score 15):

From within a `beforeEach`, try `this.currentTest.title`.

Example:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  console.log(this.currentTest.title); 
})
```

Using Mocha `3.4.1`.

Comment: I have tried this with Mocha ^9.2.1 but I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test')`.
When I log `this.currentTest` to the console, it returns `undefined`

Comment: be sure to avoid passing arrow functions to mocha, which will inhibit access to the mocha context through `this`

Answer (score 5):

For mocha "^5.1.0" you can use `console.log(this.ctx.test.title);`

Comment: I have tried this with mocha ^9.2.1 but I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test')` error

Answer (score -3):

Inside any test method

```
it('test method name'), function()  { var testName= this.test.title; }
```

and you may use :

```
afterEach(function(){
    console.log(this.currentTest.title); //displays test title for each test method      
});
```