# Retrieve the current test's name within a Mocha test using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, bdd

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304280/how-can-i-retrieve-the-current-tests-name-within-a-mocha-test), but has one very significant difference: typescript is used.

I'm trying to get current test title from within the mocha test, but since typescript is used this code does not work:

```
import 'mocha';

describe("top", () => {
    console.log(this.title);
    console.log(this.fullTitle());

    it("test", () => {
        console.log(this.test.title);
        console.log(this.test.fullTitle());
    });
});
```

Typescripts obscures `this` and access to native JavaScript's `this` is not possible anymore.

Has anyone faced this situation before? Is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you use TypeScript, it's that you use arrow functions.

Arrow functions automatically bind `this` to the `this` where the function is defined.

Since they all use arrow functions, your `this` is the `this` found at the global level, which is either `global` outside of strict mode, or `undefined` in strict mode. (Since you're using ES modules, per-spec you are automatically in strict mode)

import 'mocha';

```
describe("top", function() {
    console.log(this.title);
    console.log(this.fullTitle());

    it("test", function() {
        console.log(this.test.title);
        console.log(this.test.fullTitle());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you I will be more accurate with arrow functions in the future!

Comment: There is no way to do this with arrow functions?

Comment: @distante Not if you want Mocha to supply the `this`. `() => whatever` is the equivalent of `(function() { return whatever; }).bind(this)`.