# How to get test suite/ test case name in webdriverIO's screenshot name?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, mocha.js, webdriver-io

```
describe("Test_suite_name",()=>{
  it("Test_case_name",()=>{
      //some code
   })
 })
```

Expected : How to get either `"Test suite name"`which is under describe block or `"Test case name"`

Output should be:  `Test_suite_name.png` or `Test_case_name.png`

Answer (score 4):

Why not using the available hooks in the wdio.conf.js file?

```
beforeTest: function (test, context) {
    console.log('--- Running test: ' + test.title);
},
```

Comment: best answer and the way to do centrally.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option

```
  let mySpec = it("tests a feature", function(){
    this.specName = mySpec.getFullName();  // "tests a feature"
    browser.goto("https://google.com");
    expect(browser.title).toContain("Google");
  });
```

OR

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specStarted: function(result) {
        console.log(result.fullName);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I got alternate solution

`describe("Test_suite_name",function(){
     it("Test_case_name",function(){
            console.log(this.test.title)
         })
     })`

Answer (score 0):

There is a full answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26534968/209288 about Mocha not specifically Wedbdriver IO but it works the same.

```
describe("Test_suite_name",()=>{
  it("Test_case_name",()=>{

      this.test.fullTitle() // the describe + it names

      this.test.title       // just the it name
   })
 })
```